# How to define serial number with 2 ng-repeats?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

$index is not working as when the inner ng-repeat fires it executes $index and when it is executed fully it nulls the value of $index for the outer ng-repeat.How to give serial number in that case.?

Comment: Storing serial number in database with an auto incrementing variable will not be feasible as to retrieve it I have to fire multiple GET/POST  requests which will slow down the application.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "define" serial numbers with ng-repeat. The ng-repeat directive should really only be used to iterate through data that already exists, not create it as it iterates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use ng-repeat, it creates a child scope. Therefore in case of nested ng-repeats, you can reach the parent via `$parent`.

hence, you could do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in serial1">
  <div ng-repeat="b in serial2">
    a is {{$parent.$index}}, b is {{$index}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <tbody ng-repeat="x in data">
      <tr ng-repeat="y in x.values">
      <td>{{$parent.$index}}</td>
      <td>{{y.item}}</td>
      <td>{{y.quantity}}</td>
      <td>{{y.newprice}}</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="singleModel">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"  ng-click="remove($index)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

Comment: Still it is not working ! Above commented is my code